# Getting changed/failed hosts list from a previous task | Ansible

Tags: ansible

All,

Example: If i've got 20 hosts for a playbook and running them with Serial:10, below shell command runs on 10 hosts at a time. Once done handler task is called, wherein the task which creates dict (_dict) doesn't give a dictionary output thus the second task - Failed host - failed with mentioned error.

```
      - name: Run some shell command
        shell: "echo 2 > /abcd/abcd.txt"
        when: random condition is satisfied
        register: update2
        ignore_errors: yes
        notify: abc_handler

   - handler:
      - name: abcd_handler
        set_fact:
           _dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(
                    ansible_play_hosts|map('extract', hostvars, 'update2'))) }}"
        run_once: true
  

      - name: Find failed hosts 
        set_fact:
           _failed:  "{{ _dict|dict2items|json_query('[?value.failed].key') }}"
        run_once: true
```

Handler First task output:

```
        "changed: false"
            "ansible_facts": {
                "_dict": "{u'host1': {'stderr_lines': [], u'changed': True,...u'host2':.....u'host10'}"
```

2nd handler task gives the mentioned error when the dict2items is run for above values.

Thank you.

Comment: "Testing tasks result — Ansible Documentation" https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"List of hosts where a certain task executed, changed something, or got failed."***

A: For example, the command makes no changes at *test_11* changes the file at *test_12*, and fails at *test_13*

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  tasks:
    - shell:
        cmd: "echo 2 > /tmp/test/abcd.txt"
        creates: /tmp/test/abcd.txt
      register: update1
      ignore_errors: true
```

```yaml
TASK [shell] ***********************************************************
changed: [test_12]
fatal: [test_13]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd: echo 2 > /tmp/test/abcd.txt
  delta: '0:00:00.045992'
  end: '2021-04-25 23:22:31.623804'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 2
  start: '2021-04-25 23:22:31.577812'
  stderr: '/bin/sh: cannot create /tmp/test/abcd.txt: Permission denied'
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
...ignoring
ok: [test_11]
```

Let's create a dictionary with the data first, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                        zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                            map('extract', hostvars, 'update1'))) }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    test_11:
      changed: false
      cmd: echo 2 > /tmp/test/abcd.txt
      failed: false
      rc: 0
      stdout: skipped, since /tmp/test/abcd.txt exists
      stdout_lines:
      - skipped, since /tmp/test/abcd.txt exists
    test_12:
      changed: true
      cmd: echo 2 > /tmp/test/abcd.txt
      delta: '0:00:00.032474'
      end: '2021-04-25 23:14:36.361510'
      failed: false
      rc: 0
      start: '2021-04-25 23:14:36.329036'
      stderr: ''
      stderr_lines: []
      stdout: ''
      stdout_lines: []
    test_13:
      changed: true
      cmd: echo 2 > /tmp/test/abcd.txt
      delta: '0:00:00.054980'
      end: '2021-04-25 23:14:35.565811'
      failed: true
      msg: non-zero return code
      rc: 2
      start: '2021-04-25 23:14:35.510831'
      stderr: '/bin/sh: cannot create /tmp/test/abcd.txt: Permission denied'
      stderr_lines:
      - '/bin/sh: cannot create /tmp/test/abcd.txt: Permission denied'
      stdout: ''
      stdout_lines: []
```

Note that *test_11* is reported **ok** not **skipped** despite the registered variable showing "*stdout: skipped, since /tmp/test/abcd.txt exists*".

The analysis is now trivial, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _failed:  "{{ _dict|dict2items|json_query('[?value.failed].key') }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives the list of the failed hosts

```yaml
  _failed:
  - test_13
```

and the next task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _changed: "{{ (_dict|dict2items|json_query('[?value.changed].key'))|
                       difference(_failed) }}"
        _ok: "{{ _dict|dict2items|json_query('[?value.changed == `false`].key') }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  _changed:
  - test_12

  _ok:
  - test_11
```

Note that

1. The failed hosts need to be subtracted from the changed hosts because failed hosts are also reported as changed.
2. There will be no registered variable if a task is skipped.

---

**Serial**

Split the playbook into 2 plays if *serial* is used. e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  serial: 10
  tasks:
    - shell:
        cmd: "echo 2 > /tmp/test/abcd.txt"
        creates: /tmp/test/abcd.txt
      register: update1
      ignore_errors: true

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(
                        ansible_play_hosts|map('extract', hostvars, 'update1'))) }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Getting "dict2items requires a dictionary, got <type 'unicode'> instead" error when the no. of hosts involved are >10, the output of create dictionary isn't in dict form either. Known case ?

Comment: Known case? Not to me. Is it to you? [edit] your question and make it [mre] if you want to share.

Comment: the set_fact task is in handler and am calling it when the shell task runs (using notify). So how to make the set_fact task run on all hosts ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you would like to get the hosts on which the `command` task (shown in the question) failed or changed, and then target them for some other tasks.

There are two things required for this:

- If the `command` task fails, playbook execution will stop and hence none of the following tasks will run. So we need to add `ignore_errors` flag to the task
- `add_host` module to create a new group of hosts when the task failed or changed

So finally tasks like below should do the trick:

```yaml
- hosts: some_group
  serial: 1

    - name: update file count
      shell: "echo 2 > /home/ec2-user/abcd.txt"
      when:
        - count.stdout == "1"
      register: update1
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: conditionally add the hosts from current play hosts to a new group
      add_host:
        groups:
          - new_group
        host: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
      when: >
        cmd_stat is failed or
        cmd_stat is changed

# Then have a play targeting the new group
- hosts: new_group
  tasks:
  # Tasks to be performed
```

Though the use of `serial` might make the whole playbook run longer if there are lot of hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer . Though the problem with above approach is when conditional is satisfied, "ansible_play_hosts" will add entire list of hosts to new group, not the ones which changed/failed, as the same is not applied to the loop. Any way around that ?

Comment: Hmm. That's true. I think the play hosts are not required, We can directly add `ansible_hostname` or some such into a new group conditionally. I will update the answer.

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks !! As my use-case has 20-30 servers as hosts at a time, serial:1 would be a pain. Will try to figure something.