# How can I run an Ansible play book only if it was not successfully run previously.?

Tags: ansible

I need to run a playbook having a number of checks performed on hosts but needn’t run the same again if run successfully once. I would want Ansible to trigger a message saying that the checks(Ansible script) was already run successfully. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does [checking which hosts failed a playbook in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553879/) or [getting changed/failed hosts list from a previous task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249975/) answer your question? You may also have a look into [Playbook Error Handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html).

Comment: Where do you want to store the previous results that should be used in the conditions?

Comment: I first thought to touch a file on encountering an error and then to check this file at the very beginning of the playbook. But then I thought setting a variable and checking its value at the beginning will be enough. Would like to know about both of these and how to write these blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called:  --start-at-task=START_AT

This will start your playbook at the task matching the given name.

example

`ansible-playbook playbook_name --start-at-task=START_AT`
change "START_AT" with the name of the task you will start at.